# Xcode, clicking button to go to next view controller crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, crash, xcode8

I have this problem in Xcode 8, when I click on a `button` to go to the next `viewController` it crashes the **simulator**. However I have another `button` on the same `viewController` the leads to an empty `viewController` that works.

When the simulator crashes it gives me the error code:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Thanks

Comment: show the full crash report

Comment: what is error..

Comment: probably something is nil, you should debug

Comment: put the code of button action method

Comment: Show some code to see where could be the error.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have changed the name of the IBAction function, the IBAction function doesn't exist or you have multiple or no IBAction's on the button in the story board. Best thing to do is remove all IBAction's from the button and reconnect it.

For more help we will need your code, and image of storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Kindly share your code. Meanwhile if you are segueing from current view controller to next view controller through code then kindly check if you have provided the correct identifier to next view controller.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more clear if you had shared some code. But I guess you have a previous iboutlet set on your button. Right-Click on your button and remove any iboutlet that is set on your butto. Then again connect your variable by drag and drop. This should solve the problem.